# Impersonating User into remote machine

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, impersonation, start-process

I want to start User Interactive process on a computer in my network. I know administrative credentials of that machine.But as I learned to start User Interactive process, I need to acquire parent session running on that machine(session0).I am not able to do the same, can anyone help.

I tried starting process with powershell commandlets and other means. process get started by those means but it starves for CPU.

PS: i don't want to use PSexec or similar tools.